# TypeError: Cannot capture a result of an unsupported type tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.Functional

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

I would like to load a pretrained network in the inside of `create_keras_model()`
So I write this :

```py
def create_keras_model():
  
    baseModel = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path, compile=False)
 
    headModel = baseModel.output
    model_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation="softmax", name="output")(headModel)

    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=baseModel.input, outputs=model_output)
    
    return model

def model_fn():
    keras_model = create_keras_model()  
    return tff.learning.from_keras_model(keras_model, input_spec = input_spec, loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(), metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()])


@tff.tf_computation
def get_weights_from_disk():
   keras_model = create_keras_model()

   return keras_model

@tff.federated_computation
def server_init():
  # There may be state other than weights that needs to get returned from here,
  # as in the implementation of build_federated_averaging_process.
  return tff.federated_eval(get_weights_from_disk(), tff.SERVER)


old_iterproc = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(model_fn=model_fn, server_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1.0), client_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.001))
new_iterproc = tff.templates.IterativeProcess(intialize_fn=server_init,
  next_fn=old_iterproc.next)
state = new_iterproc.initialize()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from the `return` line in:

```py
@tff.tf_computation
def get_weights_from_disk():
   keras_model = create_keras_model()
   return keras_model
```

This occurs because `tff.tf_computation` decorated functions can only return `tf.Tensor` or structures (`list`, `tuple`, or `collections.OrderedDict`) of `tf.Tensor`. A `tf.keras.Model` is not one of those.

Instead of returning the `tf.keras.Model` object, we can return just the weights structure using [`tff.learning.ModelWeights.from_model`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/ModelWeights#from_model):

```py
@tff.tf_computation
def get_weights_from_disk():
   keras_model = create_keras_model()
   return tff.learning.ModelWeights.from_model(keras_model)

print(get_weights_from_disk.type_signature)
```

To use these weights later with a Keras model, one can use [`tff.learing.ModelWeights.assign_to`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/ModelWeights#assign_weights_to), or a [`tf.nest.map_structure`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nest/map_structure?version=nightly) using [`tf.Variable.assign`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable?version=nightly#assign):

```py
@tff.tf_computation
def train_model(incoming_weights):
  model = create_keras_model()
  destination_weights = tff.learning.ModelWeights.from_model(model)
  tf.nest.map_structure(lambda a, b: a.assign(b),
                        destination_weights, incoming_weights)
  ...
```